# Starting tomcat on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

I am trying to run the startup.sh command in ubuntu right from the /usr/local/tomcat/bin directory, but it tells me that "command not found"

Why would that be the case? If I do an ls -l command it shows that file right in the directory.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions :) I use tomcat 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat start

or sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 start. If you want to start it manually, you may need to chmod +x startup.sh to make it executable first.

Comment: That gives this error: Cannot find /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh
This file is needed to run this program

Comment: Did you install tomcat manually or with apt-get?

Comment: I installed it manually.

Comment: also, while there is a file called tomcat in the /etc/init.d/ diretory, when I try to call it, that generates an error "command not found"

Comment: try installing with apt-get (google it) or try this guide for hints on your manual installation:  http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/installing-tomcat-6-on-ubuntu/